# Finding whether two users have the same password

Tags: django, passwords, django-authentication

I am making a web game in Python/Django, and I want to secure it against multying.

I have already set up a system for detecting multiple users on on IP, but I would also like to check whether two users have the same password (I don't want to know their plaintext passwords).

Is this possible, seeing as Django uses salts randomised for each user?

Comment: As long as you use djangos auth, it is not possbile, except you got the needed calculation power.

Comment: Note that this knowledge also helps attackers in breaking common or re-used passwords (that's the reason Django and others bother to salt).

Comment: using IP to detect multiple users is probably not a great idea, as sometimes many users share a single IP.

Comment: It would perhaps benefit your game if you made it so that multying offers no advantage to the players. Trying to solve the multiying problem in the code might take a lot more effort than tweaking the game concept.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood
I will have a forum section where people may declare multiple IP usage, and those that do will have their in-game transactions closely monitored.

Comment: @LaundroMat
It's a nation sim based around armies and resources, multies have the potential to be a serious problem.

Comment: No, rather it's the fact that some ISPs will share a single IP among multiple users, so they all "seem" to have the same IP. It's not possible for individual end users to know this easily, so they cannot tell you. But you'll soon see for yourself if this is a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Using django-auth This is impossible.**
Read more [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/)

Comment: Funnily enough I did read the docs, thank you.
'how the storage hashing can be configured'... this section is not very clear, and why I came here for advice. Quoting the official docs at me is useless.